# Как преобразовать ответ сервера в изображение

Tags: c#, post, get

Здравствуйте есть файл с ответом на get запрос в нем находится информация от сервера и дальше через пустую строку набор символов, которое судя по всему является изображением. Вопрос как мне файл этот преобразовать в jpeg изображение.
это файл с гет запросом!

```
GET /7212330m.png HTTP/1.1
Host: savepic.org
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.172 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Range: bytes=57180-57180
If-Range: Sun, 03 May 2015 14:44:13 GMT
```

а это файл с ответом на него:

> HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content Server: nginx/1.0.15 Date: Wed, 05 Oct
>   2016 10:40:32 GMT Content-Type: image/jpeg Content-Length: 1
>   Last-Modified: Sun, 03 May 2015 14:44:13 GMT Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Range: bytes 57180-57180/180675
>
> UHTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content Server: nginx/1.0.15 Date: Wed, 05 Oct
>   2016 10:40:33 GMT Content-Type: image/jpeg Content-Length: 123495
>   Last-Modified: Sun, 03 May 2015 14:44:13 GMT Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Range: bytes 57180-180674/180675
>
> UґыГ8r~q!AnзПёzчv·µмbIЅ\2Ћ’Jj'™GЁJ'$:;љ•U"Бk}Я‹к±И)Љ\"ЅЈтq·

и так далее

Comment: У вас файл загружался по частям. Вам надо для начала собрать все части (внимание на заголовки Range и Content-Range)

Comment: Есть файлы загруженные полностью, просто пример немного некорректен.

Answer (score 1):

Если не применялось специальных методов кодирования (проверьте заголовки Content-Encoding и Transport-Encoding) - то достаточно обрезать заголовки. Следите за окончаниями строк - нельзя позволять выбранному инструменту их заменять на "нужные".

Проверить, как ведет себя ваш инструмент с окончаниями строк можно открыв файл с запросом и сразу же сохранив обратно. Размер файла не должен поменяться.

Также обратите внимание на заголовок запроса Range и заголовок ответа Content-Range. Ваш файл загружался по частям.

---

PS как вы получили файл с "сырым" запросом? Если у вас есть возможность повторить эксперимент, я бы советовал использовать [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) для просмотра запросов.

Comment: Пример который я привел немного не корректен, т.к. здесь файл загружался по частям, есть файлы которые полностью загружались без Content-range. И если в заголовке не упоминается Content-Encoding как я понимаю кодировка не используется? Могу ли я гет запросом запросить файл с пост ответом? и отрезав загловоки получить на выходе изображение?

Comment: @TarasM. что такое "пост ответ"?

Comment: Подразумеваю, файл в котором хранится информация с пост запроса. Второй фрагмент в вопросе.

Comment: @TarasM. как на гет-запрос вы можете получить "ответ поста"? В чем, по-вашему, вообще заключается принципиальное различие между гет- и пост-ответами?

Comment: Ну в принципе её нет)

Comment: @TarasM. вот вы и ответили на свой вопрос...

Answer (score 0):

Если полученный текст действительно изображение, то такой код конвертирует его

```
public Image imageFromByte(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

А дальше уже можно сохранить её в нужном формате

Comment: Как можно проверить является ли данная последовательность изображением?

Comment: @TarasM. попробовать конвертировать и посмотреть -- К.О.

Comment: @TarasM.http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616500/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F