# Как можно проверить валидность изображения?

Tags: c#, .net, графика

Как мне узнать, что файл представляет собой картинку, а не переименованный в *.jpg *.txt файл? Пробовал через Image загружать левый файл, но словил ошибку нехватки озу, хотя думал, что вылетит что-то про неизвестный формат.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Этот метод простой, но он нехороший, т.к. в случае TXT будет исключение
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">путь к файлу</param>
    /// <returns>текстовое сообщение</returns>
    private static string GetTypeImageFromImageFile(string file)
    {
        try
        {
            using (System.Drawing.Image image = Image.FromFile(file))
            {
                if (image.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg))
                {
                    return "Это jpg";
                }
                if (image.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png))
                {
                    return "Это png";
                }
                if (image.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp))
                {
                    return "Это bmp";
                }
                // и т.д. другие форматы

                //
                return String.Empty;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "Это точно не графический файл.";
        }
    }
```

Вариант 2

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Этот метод лучше, но придется поковыряться в сигнатурах :)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">путь к файлу</param>
    /// <returns>текстовое сообщение</returns>
    private static string GetTypeImageByHead(string file)
    {
        //за сигнатурами сюда https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

        List<string> png = "89 50 4E 47".Split().ToList();
        List<string> jpg = "FF D8 FF DB".Split().ToList();
        List<string> jpeg = "FF D8 FF E0".Split().ToList();

        List<string> fileHead = new List<string>();
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                string bit = stream.ReadByte().ToString("X2");
                fileHead.Add(bit);
            }
        }

        if (!png.Except(fileHead).Any())
        {
            return "Это png";
        }
        if (!jpg.Except(fileHead).Any())
        {
            return "Это jpg";
        }
        if (!jpeg.Except(fileHead).Any())
        {
            return "Это jpeg";
        }

        return "Неизвестный формат.";
    }
```

Comment: Про первый вариант написано в вопросе. Второй во-первых, зачем-то сравнивает строки вместо байтов, а во-вторых, проверяет только префикс, но не формат.

Comment: @Qwertiy Первый вариант я дал, для тех кто совсем не в теме. Второй, ну да, строки, т.к. я брал сигнатуры из википедии и для "прозрачности" источника сравниваемых данных, так сказать.

Comment: `byte[] png = {0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47};` же.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну ОК, напишите свой пример с байтами. Я писал, чтоб было максимально ясно откуда взялись данные для сравнения.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант — это просто отлавливать `OutOfMemoryException`, и считать, что формат неправильный в случае его появления. [Документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) гласит:

> `OutOfMemoryException`:
>
> The file does not have a valid image format.
>
> -or-
>
> GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file

Таким образом, выброс `OutOfMemoryException` — официальный метод сообщения фреймворка о неправильном формате. Он и правда немного контринтуитивный, но с документацией не поспоришь.

Остальные методы определения неправильного формата кажутся мне менее надёжными.

Comment: Таким образом мой вариант 1 выглядит лучшим в сравнении с 2. Мне всегда вдалбливали, что методы вызывающие  эксепшены хуже методов, которые не вызывают их, т.к. как-то все-таки решают проблему иначе.

Comment: @Bulson: Бывают исключения, которых избежать невозможно. Вот [моя любимая статья Эрика](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) по этому поводу.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю...

Comment: @VladD, а если здоровенный файл формата *.tiff будет грузится? Я встречал файлы весом 2 гб=> наверное вылетит ошибка=> хоть файл и картинка, но я его посчитаю неверным.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Ну это да. Но с другой стороны ни «неправильный», ни реально слишком большой файл система обработать не в состоянии. Так что я бы в этой точке сообщил пользователю именно это: «Программа не в состоянии обработать ваш файл. Скорее всего, он неправильного или неподдерживаемого формата, повреждён или просто слишком большой.»

Comment: @iluxa1810: Интересно, что текстовые форматы картинок существуют. Например, [PGM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html).